# A script in gitlab ci that runs before each job?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Say, I want to set some environment variables that are used in all jobs.

How do I do that in a sane way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to use before and after script. The nice thing about it is you can overload it for a job if needed
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#before_script-and-after_script

Answer (score 2):

You could add a top-level `variables` section to your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
variables:
  MY_VAR: "some_value"
```